# How can i make celery retry the for a requests until succesfull

Tags: python, django, python-requests, celery

Trying to post data to the back-end service if the service is offline i want celery to keep making requests until successful

i keep getting the requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
Max retries exceeded with url

i have tried using the request retry class as this is not the solution 
as it does not preserve any data if celery goes offline i am looking for an solution in which celery only keeps trying

```
@shared_task(queue='development',autoretry_for=(Exception,ConnectionError))
def myfunction:
     response = requests.post(URL),headers={"Content-Type":"application/json"},
        json=obj)
```

Comment: I am not sure what's the problem with your solution, the `autoretry_for` is the way to go I think

Comment: i am getting Exception occured during handling of the execption request libraby throws max retry error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any looking for this answer

`@shared_task(queue='development',autoretry_for=(Exception,ConnectionError))
def myfunction:
     response = requests.post(URL),headers={"Content-Type":"application/json"},
        json=obj)
        except ConnectionError as exc:
        raise myfunction.retry(exc=exc)
    except Exception as exc:
        raise myfunction.retry(exc=exc)`